# how to adjust line spacing of nested UL list items

Tags: css, css-selectors, r-markdown

In web-bound documents generated from Rmarkdown, I have mini chapter tables of contents formatted as s with two levels of list items.

```
<div class="chaptercontents">
#### Chapter contents {-}
* Cholera 
    + Farr's Diagrams 
    + Farr's Natural Law of Cholera
    + The Transcendent Effect of Water

* John Snow on Cholera
    + The Broad Street Pump
    + The Neighborhoods Map

* Re-visioning the Broad Street Pump
* Graphical Successes and Failures
    + The Answer: A Bug
    + Florence Nightingale's Graphical Success
</div>
```

I'm using this style for chaptercontents in my CSS file:

```
.chaptercontents {
  background-color: #daeff0;
}

.chaptercontents li {
  line-height: 6px;
}
```

However, the spacing is off for the first item of every 2nd levels list. How can I correct this?

[image]

Comment: Have any code you can post? Hard to tell otherwise.

Comment: Use a percent for '.chaptercontents li { line-height: ... }` as you (probably) want it to be some size of its parent (a LI or UL container or BODY even). BTW: CSS 101...

Comment: I know this is CSS 101, but I'm a CSS-newbie. What do you mean 'Use a percent' %